# How to display windows titles at the bottom of the screen using Byobu?

Tags: command-line, byobu, zsh

I'm using Byobu with zsh. As you can see in the screenshot below, all the windows created have "-" as their title. My colleagues using bash can see the program being run (`bash`, `python`, `vim`, `ssh`, etc.). How can I achieve the same?

Thanks in advance!

[image: A terminal with Byobu]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour appears to be by design when you're using the `tmux` back-end for `byobu` (default behaviour).

When you run `byobu-screen` you will see this functionality out-of-the-box.

If you look in the `/usr/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux` file, you can see the line that binds the <kbd>F2</kbd> key to open a new window:

```
bind-key -n F2 new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}" \; rename-window "-"
```

What do you know? The sneaky little fella renames the window to `-` as it's created.

You can override this behaviour by adding a line to your `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf` file:

```
echo 'bind-key -n F2 new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"' >> ~/.byobu/.tmux.conf
```

For some reason, this still doesn't work on the first window.

Comment: Thanks! The solution you propose doesn't work on the first window because the first window is not triggered by pressing F2 ;-)

Comment: FYI: it seems that the first window isn't renamed to `-` if I start a session by `byobu new`.